# In CnosDB Why Design Two Independent Storage Sets for Index and Data Storage

Tags: storage, cnosdb

In many storage systems, such as MySQL and MongoDB, indexes and data are usually stored as a whole, which helps to maintain the atomicity of the system everywhere.
Why is CnosDB separate and what are the benefits of this?